# Travel to UK with passport having less than 6 months' validity

Tags: visas, passports, paperwork

The passport is getting expired in Oct 2019 and  travel to UK is in the month of June 2019.

So the passport is less than 6 months validity from the date of travel.

Do I need to renew the passport before travel?

Do I need to apply for fresh visa once the passport is renewed ?

Can I travel with the same passport and visa?

Answer (score 6):

You wouldn't have been issued a visa if the passport weren't valid for travel. The UK only [requires that a passport is valid for your entire stay](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk).

> You must have a valid passport to enter the UK. It must be valid for the whole of your stay.

If you decide to renew your passport, [you can still travel to the UK without getting a new visa](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa). You will need to show both your new passport and your UK visa in the expired passport. You might need to request that your old passport is returned to you, since not all countries do this automatically.

> You can use the valid visa in your expired passport when you’re travelling to and from the UK. You’ll need to travel with your expired and your new passport.

Comment: @giorgio As far as I know this is not the case for UK visas. If the visa is a vignette, the UK was happy to issue them beyond the length of the passport validity. And now, almost all long term visas are issued as BRPs, completely decoupling their validity from the passport.